# Скраппинг веб-сайтов на Android | Kotlin

Tags: android, парсер, kotlin, web-scraping, chromedriver

**Какие библиотеки использовать для скраппинга сайтов на андройд?** Хочу сделать приложение на контенте другого сайта, но проблема в том, что он загружает данные через js. Я пытался его проанализировать, но там целое ядро [bable, native (react)].

Разбирать такое, естественно, мне не хочется. Пытался использовать Selenium, но толку нет, потому что не понимаю, как правильно его настроить, чтобы после билда все работало. Jsoup не ожидает загрузки скриптов.

Comment: По другому - никак. Ковыряйте селениум пока не заработает (если оно вообще может заработать). Можно дико извращаться загружая страницы в невидимое WebView и потом из него доставать итоговый HTML когда он туда окончательно весь загрузится. Однако это будет костыльно и работать будет криво и медленно. Основная проблема тут в том, что на андроиде парсить сайты - путь в никуда. Парсить надо на сервере, отдавая на клиент уже распаршенные и, желательно, структурированные данные. Засим и не будет никогда хороших решений именно для андроида.